# How do i get the input from TextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm trying to make a simple calculator GUI using Netbeans.

How do I input integer and String from `angka1`,`angka2`, and `operator1` so it can be used in `private void btnHitungMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)`

```
private void angka1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
            nilai1=Integer.parseInt(angka1.getText());
        }
private void angka2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
                nilai2=Integer.parseInt(angka2.getText());
    }
private void operator1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       operator=operator1.getText();
    }




private void btnHitungMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
        double jawaban=0;
        if(operator=="+")
            jawaban=nilai1+nilai2;
        else if(operator=="-")
            jawaban=nilai1-nilai2;
        else if(operator=="*")
            jawaban=nilai1*nilai2;
        else if(operator=="/")
            jawaban=nilai1/nilai2;            
        String hasil=Double.toString(jawaban);

        txtHasil.setText(hasil);
```

This is the GUI I'm trying to make:

[image: The GUI I'm trying to make]
As you can see it doesn't seem to work.I expect the GUI to give the correct result in the TextField to work when i type a number and also an operator in the TextField above. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

operator=='+' does not compare the string. it checks the object.
Create a **MouseClicked Event** by RightClicking on Hitung Button **Events>Mouse>MouseClicked**

```
  private void HitungMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
     nilai1 = Integer.parseInt(angka1.getText());
     nilai2=Integer.parseInt(angka2.getText());
     operator=operator1.getText();

     double jawaban=0;
    if(operator.equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
        jawaban=nilai1+nilai2;
    else if(operator.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
        jawaban=nilai1-nilai2;
    else if(operator.equalsIgnoreCase("*"))
        jawaban=nilai1*nilai2;
    else if(operator.equalsIgnoreCase("/"))
        jawaban=nilai1/nilai2;            
    String hasil=Double.toString(jawaban);

    txtHasil.setText(hasil);

}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of an uppercase/lowercase "+"? Or any of these symbols?

Comment: there is no uppercase/lowercase "+".you can use equals() also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
private void btnHitungMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       nilai1=Integer.parseInt(angka1.getText()); 
       nilai2=Integer.parseInt(angka2.getText()); 
       operator=operator1.getText();                                     
        double jawaban=0;
        if(operator=="+")
            jawaban=nilai1+nilai2;
        else if(operator=="-")
            jawaban=nilai1-nilai2;
        else if(operator=="*")
            jawaban=nilai1*nilai2;
        else if(operator=="/")
            jawaban=nilai1/nilai2;
        else{}            
        String hasil=Double.toString(jawaban);

        txtHasil.setText(hasil);
```